# Micro-service architecture need advice

Tags: architecture, microservices, separation-of-concerns

We work in agile mode with two different teams/applications, we are facing a new situation and we need your advice. The front-end of the application A (developed by team A) is now needing a service from micro-service B (which is developed by team B). Should the front-end A directly ask the micro-service B or would you prefer that it goes through micro-service A ? is it a matter of separation of concerns here ?

Help/advise would be highly appreciated.

Thanx a lot!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front-end A should call Microservice B directly. As in your solution 2.

Simplifying, microservice architectures are supposed to be composed of small services that provide single functions in a self contained and self manage way.

By having your solution 1, you break that principle.

MicroserviceA does not need to call Microservice B to perform its function. Frontend A needs it. Keep microservices simple and focused, otherwise you're not doing microservice architecture, you're doing something else.

The best way to approach a microservice architecture is to approach each microservice functionality in isolation, as if it was the only microservice that exists and then add dependencies (calls to other microservices) on demand, don't consider the needs of the clients of your microservice, think about what that particular service offers.

Comment: I understand the logic you describe here but do you find "normal" that a front-end depends on several micro-services ? thanks

Comment: That depends on what you call "front-end". 

If you have a front-end composed of an MVC, then your controller will call the appropriate microservice, obtain the data, generate a model and pass it on to the view. The the set of models, view and controllers is your front-end. If you identify "view" with front-end and "MC" with backend then your "back-end" is not a microservice and hence the conflict on your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Tonz of possible solutions.

1) Try to add the new layer like Nginx reverse proxy in front of the backends.

2) Pretty much the same. Use API gateway.

3) Call the backend B from the backend A directly and create new endpoints in the backend A

4) Duplicate data and logic

5) extract one more backend

6) etc.

7) etc...

It really depends on many factors like the common architecture, code organization, development rules, tooling... There is no one silver bullet.